# Is there any ps command to disable password hash sync?

Tags: azure-powershell

I use a ps command to disable the AADC, but the password hash sync is still enabled.  Is there any command to disable it?[a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kd0mV.png)

Answer (score 1):

There is no Powershell cmdlet to disable password hash sync.

Based on [Set-MsolDirSyncFeature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/set-msoldirsyncfeature?view=azureadps-1.0#description), `PasswordSync` can be used with this cmdlet. But after a test, I found that it's not supported. This document seems to be maintained no longer.

I found another document then: [Azure AD Connect sync service features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-syncservice-features). It states that  Password Hash Sync is configured by Azure AD Connect and cannot be modified by `Set-MsolDirSyncFeature`.

After confirming with Azure AD support, there is indeed not a cmdlet to make it. But there is a workaround to make password hash sync ineffective. Please refer to [Enable synchronization of password hashes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/tutorial-configure-password-hash-sync#enable-synchronization-of-password-hashes).

We can see there is a script to synchronize on-premises account NTLM and Kerberos password hashes to Azure AD.

```
# Define the Azure AD Connect connector names and import the required PowerShell module
$azureadConnector = "<CASE SENSITIVE AZURE AD CONNECTOR NAME>"
$adConnector = "<CASE SENSITIVE AD DS CONNECTOR NAME>"

Import-Module "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Azure AD Sync\Bin\ADSync\ADSync.psd1"
Import-Module "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Azure Active Directory Connect\AdSyncConfig\AdSyncConfig.psm1"

# Create a new ForceFullPasswordSync configuration parameter object then
# update the existing connector with this new configuration
$c = Get-ADSyncConnector -Name $adConnector
$p = New-Object Microsoft.IdentityManagement.PowerShell.ObjectModel.ConfigurationParameter "Microsoft.Synchronize.ForceFullPasswordSync", String, ConnectorGlobal, $null, $null, $null
$p.Value = 1
$c.GlobalParameters.Remove($p.Name)
$c.GlobalParameters.Add($p)
$c = Add-ADSyncConnector -Connector $c

# Disable and re-enable Azure AD Connect to force a full password synchronization
Set-ADSyncAADPasswordSyncConfiguration -SourceConnector $adConnector -TargetConnector $azureadConnector -Enable $false
Set-ADSyncAADPasswordSyncConfiguration -SourceConnector $adConnector -TargetConnector $azureadConnector -Enable $true
```

**If you do not run the last line, password hash sync will no longer take effect.**

**But, the "password hash sync" will still be shown as "Enabled" on Azure portal.**

So this method can only make password hash sync ineffective, not change the state of "password hash sync" on portal.

We have to disable it in AAD connect currently.